# Java 2D graphics - drawing a rectangle

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, graphics2d

So I am quite new to Java programming and programming in general and please excuse my lack of knowledge. I am trying to draw a simple rectangle on the screen with some given coordinates.

Here is my code in the Drawer Class:

```
public class Drawer extends JPanel {

public static void drawPixel(Graphics g, int x, int y) {
    g.fillRect(x, y, 5, 5);
}

}
```

And here is the code I am trying to use in the main class:

```
Drawer drawer = new Drawer();
Drawer.drawPixel(Graphics g, i9, i10);
```

So I really don't understand what the first argument is for. It gives me an error saying it can't resolve "Symbol g". i9 and i10 are the coordinates I want it to draw the rectangle at.

Thanks in advance for any help. :)

Comment: You should check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step1.html which leads you to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step3.html

Comment: Spend some time going through the Oracle Swing Tutorial.  It will show you how to put the GUI pieces together.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/

Answer (score 4):

You can not draw something like that. You should use `paintComponent()` method to draw.

Check this:

```
public class RectDrawer extends JPanel {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    public RectDrawer(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.fillRect(x, y, 5, 5);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much the best way to do it if you're working in Swing - I like it.

Comment: `paintComponent` is not static, nor public (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29)

Comment: The static should not be there, but otherwise (based on my experience) that is the correct way to override it.. no?

Comment: @Surveon `public` works, but there is absolutely no need for the clients of your panel to call that method directly. They made it `protected` in `JComponent` for a reason. As a general rule: don't make a method `public` unless you absolutely have to. In this case you don't.

Comment: Understood. I have actually made this mistake several times now that I think about it - thank you for your insight.

Answer (score 1):

`Drawer.drawPixel(Graphics g, i9, i10);` is probably the source of your issue.

You are passing (as the first argument) something along the lines of `Graphics g`. Consider just passing `g` by itself without the `Graphics` bit - that should solve your problem.

The `Graphics g` object refers to the graphical context - this is what effectively draws stuff onto the screen. By calling methods on it, you can then literally draw things where a user can see them.

Using [JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) as an example, you can override its [paintComponent()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29) method. You'll notice this method takes in a Graphics object - you can then use this to draw stuff in the panel.

Answer (score 0):

Some of your code isn't right like Graphics g. I'm not going to go over it since others have but I recommend you look at some tutorials. If your new to java overall then check out:

[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P0_2JKxCq-0)

You should check out that video series, it teaches you a solid understanding of the java syntax and basics. Then after that you can start checking out tutorials like this:

[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ByucQN42OOY)

That one teaches you a really good solid understanding of making complicated games in Java. I recommend even intermediate and advanced Java programmer to check it out. When I started I looked at other tutorials and they mainly stopped halfway through, had terrible mistakes or something like that. This video teaches it a whole simpler way.